# How to use cv::Mat::convertTo

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a function which takes a cv::Mat of arbitrary type, converts it to a float image, processes it and converts it back to it's original type. The problem is that non of the simple ways I've come up with works. Here's what I tried so far:

```
cv::Mat process(const cv::Mat& input)// input might be float
{
    cv::Mat_<float> result(input.size());

   // Generate result based on input.
    result = ...;

    // Now convert result back to the type of input:
#if 1
    // Version 1: Converting in place crashes with:
    // OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in cv::_OutputArray::create,
    // file ...\OpenCV\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1365
    if (result.type() != input.type())
        result.convertTo(result, input.type());

#else
    // Version 2: Not what you'd expect
    if (result.type() != input.type())
    {
        cv::Mat tmp;
        result.convertTo(tmp, input.type());
        result = tmp;// This line doesn't replace result, but converts tmp back to float.
    }
#endif
    return result;
}
```

The calling function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat_<float> a =  cv::Mat_<float>::zeros(256, 256);
    cv::Mat a1 = process(a);

    cv::Mat_<uint16_t> b =  cv::Mat_<uint16_t>::zeros(256, 256);
    cv::Mat b1 = process(b);
    assert(b1.type()==CV_16UC1);
    return 0;
}
```

So, what would be the standard way of doing this?
I'm using OpenCV 2.4.10 on Windows.

Comment: Can't you just `return tmp;` instead of `result = tmp`? `tmp` already has the right type and representation.

Comment: can you add `std::cout << a1.type() << " and " << b1.type() << std::endl` and tell us?

Comment: ah... the problem probably is, that you use those template Mats and not the openCV types! can you try `cv::Mat b =  cv::Mat::zeros(256, 256, 16UC1);` instead?

Comment: @AlanStokes That would be a workaround for this specific minimal case, but in my real function i continue to process 'result' after that line.

Comment: @Micka a1.type() == CV_32FC1 and b1.type() == CV_16UC1.

Comment: @Micka You are right that my use of templated Mats probably has to do with the problem, but your suggested change doesn't solve it. Are you saying that I should refrain from using templated Mats?

Comment: wait... `a1.type() == CV_32FC1` and `b1.type() == CV_16UC1`? isn't that exactly what you wanted? So where's the problem?

Comment: ok... I tried it... input type isn't important, but your intermediate type makes problems. If you change it to `cv::Mat result(input.size(), CV_32FC1);` everything works, at least for me... not sure whether that is a bug or `.convertTo` doesnt work from template Mats.

Comment: @bgp2000 Then you could instead continue to process `tmp`. If you declare `result` as `Mat_<float>`, you're stuck with `float` as the representation. The solution is to not do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the templated `cv::Mat_<float>`. Apparently `cv::Mat::convertTo()` cannot take a `Mat_<>` as an output. Additionally `cv::Mat_<float>::operator=()` works differently than `cv::Mat:operator=()`. It implicitly converts the image to the appropriate format.

It makes sense once you think of it.